# AngularJS inline edit in 1.0.3

Tags: angularjs

I found an [excellent fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/XuhzP/64/) showing an inline edit directive in AngularJS 0.10. Unfortunately, the code doesn't work in the post-1.0 releases. Does anyone have an example of similar functionality in a recent Angular release?

I managed to make some progress by changing `model: 'accessor'` to `model: '&'`, but when I press enter, the text value is unchanged. The [AngularJS documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) about the `scope` parameter of a directive definition object is completely impenetrable to me.

Comment: Of course, as soon as I post this I find a [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/C5e4j/).

Comment: here's a good answer about different ways to bind to data in an isolate scope http://stackoverflow.com/a/13033249/527968

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a simple  **bi-directional binding** use `model: '='` instead of `model: '&'`

Directive:

```
app.directive('inlineEdit', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',           
        templateUrl: 'componentTpl.html',
        scope: {
            model: '=' 
        }
    };
});
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="componentTpl.html">  
    <span ng-hide="editMode" ng-click="editMode=true;value=model">{{model}}</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="value" ng-show="editMode" ng-model-instant ng-enter="editMode=false" ng-change="model=value"/>
</script>
```

**jsFiddler**: http://jsfiddle.net/XuhzP/147/

Comment: Could have sworn I tried `=` at one point as well. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 1):

You should use '=' binding (bi-directional) and then directly bind to 'model' property of scope.

Here is corrected sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/tjTsNiQ7t0xMWkCEAzwo?p=preview

(its a same solution as @bmleite gave)