# Passing Attributes in HandsonTable Angular Directive <<ui-handsontable> from scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, handsontable

I am using handsontable angular directive in my project.
normally we define the [handsontable](https://github.com/warpech/angular-ui-handsontable) as

```
<ui-handsontable minSpareRows="2" stretchH="'hybrid'" datarows="item in items">
```

I want to have the values of attributes like minSpareRows from scope varrible like

I have tried

- minSpareRows={{minrows}}
- ng-attr-minSpareRows="{{minrows}}"

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Where exactly do you want these attributes? You could do something like:

```
angular.module('yourApp')
 .directive('uiHandsontable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.minSpareRows = attrs.minSpareRows
        }
    };
});
```

And that will attach it to the scope of your directive so in the html template for the directive you could call {{minSpareRows}}

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032621/need-some-examples-of-binding-attributes-in-custom-angularjs-tags) . One of the ans said:

> The magic is mostly in the scope: declaration in your directive
>   definition. having any scope: {} in there will "isolate" the scope
>   from the parent, meaning it gets it's own scope... without that, it
>   would use the parent's scope. The rest of the magic is in the scope's
>   properties: scope: { 'internalScopeProperty' :
>   '=externalAttributeName' }... where the = represents a two way binding
>   scenario. If you change that = to a @ you'll see it just allows you to
>   pass a string as an attribute to the directive. The & is for executing
>   functions from the parent scope's context.

so I went to the code of the handsontable angular directive "angular-ui-handsontable.full.js" and changed the line

```
var htOptions = ['data', 'width', 'height', 'rowHeaders', 'colHeaders', 'colWidths', 'columns', 'cells', 'dataSchema', 'contextMenu', 'onSelection', 'onSelectionByProp', 'onBeforeChange', 'onChange', 'onCopyLimit', 'startRows', 'startCols', 'minRows', 'minCols', 'maxRows', 'maxCols', 'minSpareRows', 'minSpareCols', 'multiSelect', 'fillHandle', 'undo', 'outsideClickDeselects', 'enterBeginsEditing', 'enterMoves', 'tabMoves', 'autoWrapRow', 'autoWrapCol', 'copyRowsLimit', 'copyColsLimit', 'currentRowClassName', 'currentColClassName', 'asyncRendering', 'stretchH', 'columnSorting', 'manualColumnMove', 'manualColumnResize', 'fragmentSelection', 'scrollbarModelV', 'scrollbarModelH'];

var scopeDef = {
  selectedIndex: '=selectedindex'
};
for (var i = 0, ilen = htOptions.length; i < ilen; i++) {
  scopeDef[htOptions[i]] = '=' + htOptions[i].toLowerCase();
}
```

with

```
var htOptions = ['data', 'width', 'height', 'rowHeaders', 'colHeaders', 'colWidths', 'columns', 'cells', 'dataSchema', 'contextMenu', 'onSelection', 'onSelectionByProp', 'onBeforeChange', 'onChange', 'onCopyLimit', 'startRows', 'startCols', 'minRows', 'minCols', 'maxRows', 'maxCols', 'minSpareRows', 'minSpareCols', 'multiSelect', 'fillHandle', 'undo', 'outsideClickDeselects', 'enterBeginsEditing', 'enterMoves', 'tabMoves', 'autoWrapRow', 'autoWrapCol', 'copyRowsLimit', 'copyColsLimit', 'currentRowClassName', 'currentColClassName', 'asyncRendering', 'stretchH', 'columnSorting', 'manualColumnMove', 'manualColumnResize', 'fragmentSelection', 'scrollbarModelV', 'scrollbarModelH'];
var scopeDef = {
  selectedIndex: '=selectedindex'
};
for (var i = 0, ilen = htOptions.length; i < ilen; i++) {
  scopeDef[htOptions[i]] = '@' + htOptions[i].toLowerCase();
}
```

and then when i used

```
<ui-handsontable minSpareRows="{{cx}}" stretchH="'hybrid'" datarows="item in items">
```

it worked. I am putting this is on the request on handsontable github.